# bitcoind service daemon

Tags: bitcoind

So I am running bitcoind everything is fine and the blockchain got synced etc.
Next step is to have bitcoind starting on boot.
I get this error on starting the service after creating a `nano /etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service` the erro is `Error: Unable to create the PID file /home/path/.bitcoin/bitcoind.pid: Permission denied`

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you change `/home/path` to the home directory of the user bitcoind will run under? Or do you actually have a user called `path`?

Answer (score 1):

It look like a permission read/write error, if you are sure about the bitcoin binary you are using, then try to run your command with `sudo` at the begining of it or try a `sudo chmod 711 /etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service` which will give the proper right to the file you want to use.